Projectively normal family is very flat
Hartshorne, exercise III.9.5 (d): Show that if $X_t$ is an algebraic family of projectively normal varieties in $\mathbb{P}_k^n$, parameterized by a nonsingular curve $T$ over an algebraically closed field $k$, then $X_t$ is a very flat family of schemes.
By very flat, we mean that $\dim_{k(t)} (S_t/I_t)_d$ is independent of $t$, where $S_t/I_t$ is a homogeneous coordinate ring of $X_t\subset \mathbb{P}_{k(t)}^n$.
From the given conditions (precisely for thm 9.11), we know that $X_t$ is already a flat family, so that Hilbert polynomial is independent of $t$. Hence a natural attempt would be this, but Hilbert regularity cannot be zero if we consider, for example, an elliptic curve embedded projectively normal (as here).
I have no idea how to solve this.
